# Использование @PathVariable в конструкторе @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Суть вопроса: 
у меня есть

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = "/features/{uin}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public class RestController {

 private Modul modul;

 @Resource(name = "modulService")
 private ModuleDAO  modulService;

 ...

}
```

Параметр `{uin}` будет использоваться во всех методах для поиска сущности. Есть ли возможность найти эту сущность непосредственно при создании бина, для дальнейшего использования в методах. Например вот так:

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = "/features/{uin}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public class RestController {

 private Modul modul;

 @Resource(name = "modulService")
 private ModuleDAO  modulService;

 ...

 public RestController(@PathVariable("uin") String uin){
     this.modul = modulService.findByUin(uin);
     ...
 }

 ...

 }
```

Но мне не как не получается это сделать в конструкторе класса, говорит, мол невозможно заинжектит параметр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не думаю, что такое возможно. Конструктор контроллера вызывается один раз - на старте приложения, а не при каждом запросе, так что не получится таким образом привязать переменную из запроса.